# MY Asp.Net MVC page takes 12 secs. to load

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC Controller like this

```
public ActionResult Index(int vendor=-1, int product = -1, string error="", string mode="Shortfall")
    {
        if (Session["UserId"] == null)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        var products = DbContext.GetAllProducts();
        List<SurplusViewModel> surplusList = new List<SurplusViewModel>();
        Dictionary<int, string> searchVendor = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        Dictionary<int, string> searchProds = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        if (products.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var prod in products)
            {
                SurplusViewModel s = new SurplusViewModel(prod);
                surplusList.Add(s);
                foreach (var v in s.Vendors)
                {
                    if (!searchVendor.ContainsKey(v.CorpId))
                    {
                        searchVendor.Add(v.CorpId, v.CorpName);
                    }
                }
                if(!searchProds.ContainsKey(s.ProductId))
                    searchProds.Add(s.ProductId, s.ProductVM.ProductCode + " / " + s.ProductVM.ProductPartNo);
            }
        }
        ViewData["vendorList"] = searchVendor;
        ViewData["productList"] = searchProds;
        ViewData["selectVendor"] = vendor;
        ViewData["selectProd"] = product;
        ViewData["mode"] = mode;
        ViewBag.Message = "";
        ViewBag.Error = "";
        IEnumerable<SurplusViewModel> finalList = surplusList.OrderBy(o => o.Difference).ToList();
        if (vendor > 0)
        {
            Corporation searchcorp = DbContext.GetCorporation(vendor);
            finalList = finalList.Where(x => x.VendorNames.IndexOf(searchcorp.CorpName) >= 0);
        }
        if (product > 0)
        {
            finalList = finalList.Where(x => x.ProductId == product);
        }
        if (vendor < 0 && product < 0)
        {
            if (mode.Equals("Shortfall"))
                finalList = finalList.Where(f => f.VendorQuantity - (f.CMQuantity + f.OEMQuantity) < 0);
            else if (mode.Equals("Surplus"))
                finalList = finalList.Where(f => f.VendorQuantity - (f.CMQuantity + f.OEMQuantity) > 0);


        }
        return View(finalList);
        //return View();
    }
```

This takes about 20 seconds to load on localhost. What can I do to improve my app's loading time. If it takes 20 secs on localhost I assume it will be very slow on the internet. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Code for SurplusViewModel

```
public SurplusViewModel(Product product)
    {
        int productId = product.ProductId;
        ProductId = productId;
        ProductVM = new ProductViewModel(product);
        var saleDetsCM = from s in DbContext.GetSalesOrderDetailsFromCM()
                         where s.ProductId == productId && s.SaleStatus.Equals("Open") && (s.OrderType.ToLower().Equals("prototype") || s.OrderType.ToLower().Equals("production"))
                         orderby s.SalDetId descending
                         select s;

        var saleDetsOEM = from s in DbContext.GetSalesOrderDetailsFromOEMs()
                          where s.ProductId == productId && s.SaleStatus.Equals("Open") && (s.OrderType.ToLower().Equals("prototype") || s.OrderType.ToLower().Equals("production"))
                          orderby s.SalDetId descending
                          select s;

        var shipQty = from s in DbContext.GetAllSalesDets()
                      where s.ProductId == productId && !s.SaleStatus.Equals("Open") && (s.OrderType.ToLower().Equals("prototype") || s.OrderType.ToLower().Equals("production"))
                      orderby s.SalDetId descending
                      select s;

        CustomerOrdersFromCMs = saleDetsCM.ToList();
        CustomerOrdersFromOEMs = saleDetsOEM.ToList();
        VendorOrders = (from p in DbContext.GetPurchaseDetsForProduct(productId)
                        where p.OrderType != null && (p.OrderType.ToLower().Equals("prototype") || p.OrderType.ToLower().Equals("production"))
                        select p).ToList();
        var poIds = from v in VendorOrders
                     select v.PodPOId;
        BatchPurchaseDetails = DbContext.GetBatchPurchaseForProduct(productId).ToList();
        VendorOrderCount = 0;
        VendorQuantity = 0;
        var purchaseOrds = (from po in DbContext.GetPurchaseOrdersForProduct(productId)
                            where poIds.Contains(po.POId)
                            select po).ToList();
        List<int> vendIds = new List<int>();
        foreach (var po in purchaseOrds)
        {
            vendIds.Add(po.VendorId.Value);
        }
        var vendors = from v in DbContext.GetAllCorps()
                      where vendIds.Contains(v.CorpId)
                      select v;

        foreach (var podet in VendorOrders)
        {
            double totalbatchqty = 0;
            var purdetBatch = DbContext.GetBatchDetailsForPurchaseDet(podet.PodId);
            VendorQuantity += podet.Quantity;
            foreach (var b in purdetBatch)
            {
                totalbatchqty += b.Quantity;
                VendorQuantity -= b.Quantity;
            }
            if (totalbatchqty >= podet.Quantity)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                VendorOrderCount++;
            }

        }

        Vendors = vendors.ToList();
        VendorNames = "";
        foreach (var vnd in Vendors)
        {
            VendorNames += vnd.CorpName + ",";
        }
        if (VendorNames.Length > 0)
        {
            VendorNames = VendorNames.Substring(0, VendorNames.Length - 1);
        }


        OEMQuantity = 0;
        foreach (var item in CustomerOrdersFromOEMs)
        {
            OEMQuantity += item.Quantity;
        }

        CMQuantity = 0;
        foreach (var item in CustomerOrdersFromCMs)
        {
            CMQuantity += item.Quantity;
        }
        ShipQuantity = 0;
        foreach (var item in shipQty)
        {
            ShipQuantity += item.Quantity;
        }
        Difference = VendorQuantity - (CMQuantity + OEMQuantity);
        //TotalInsideSalesOrder = VendorOrders.Count();

    }
```

Comment: is it 12 seconds or 20 seconds?  Is it the first load, or subsequent page loads as well?

Comment: Is your controller disposing your DbContext? Also are you able to use Stopwatch to work out where the bottleneck is?

Comment: Please debug through your controller function above and identify the longest running statement. If you post that line then we would more likely be able to answer your question.

Comment: @Erik Funkenbusch Some times its 12 seconds sometimes 20 secs

Comment: Also how many products do you have? your code is loading all products, perhaps it is better to implement paging?

Comment: @failedprogramming the problem is that the client wants all on one page but there are not more than 50 products there. How can I use the stopwatch can you brief me on that

Comment: I ask again.  Is it the first load, or subsequent loads as well?

Comment: @Erik Funkenbusch all loads are the same, load re-load re-re-load.. when I debug it, the most time is spent in the foreach Statement

Comment: What is SurplusViewModel(prod) doing?

Comment: @progrAmmar Refer to http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch for examples. Create a few stopwatch objects (1 for each process) and put a breakpoint where you return the view and you should be able to see the time each process takes

Comment: #lrb foreach (var prod in products)
 is taking most time

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, I am seeing 12 secs and 12.05 now on loads and reloads. The function SurplusViewModel(prod) converts the product into the ViewModel object (which has additional properties)

Comment: @progrAmmar Are you disposing your DbContext? Also, do you have a lot of code in the SurplusViewModel Constructor?

Comment: Well, you haven't included all the code then.. You expect us to use psychic powers to know what you're doing in code we can't see?

Comment: @failedprogramming Yes, SurplusViewModel does have a lot of code and data lists (also populated by DB) but I am disposig the DataContext.Dispose with every data retrieve

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch which code would you like to see? the SurpluysViewModel constructor?

Comment: All of the code that executes in this method.  We can't help you when you tie our hands by hiding things from us.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I am not hiding anything :-S.... Let me update the code hold

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I am actually using a Library coded by my team member, I have provided the Code in the Edit. Please tell me if there is an issue there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing a ton of things wrong, or at least very poorly.  First, you're returning all records from various queries, the processing them in memory.  This is fine if there are only a few records, but you mention that there are 50 products.  How many Vendors?  How many Corporations?

You're doing several database queries, and it sounds like you're doing even more queries in sub-objects you instantiate.  All of those queries take time.  That's why you want to minimize queries by writing more inclusive single queries, and performing as much work on the sql server as possible in a single (or as few as possible) queries.

Areas you can optimize... Don't do `Count() > 0`, instead use `.Any()`.  .Any returns true after the first record it finds, rather than having to count everything and then compare that number to 0.

Another area, you're doing a foreach inside a foreach.  This creates n * m loops.  ie, if there's 2 products and 2 vendors, that's 4 loops, but if it's 3 of each, it's 9 loops, if it's 4 of each it's 16 loops.  if it's 50 of each 2500 loops.  And each one of those loops executes your SurplusViewModel constructor, which if it's a lot of code means it's going to be sloooooooow.

I see from your update, that SurplusViewModel executes at least 7 queries, maybe more.. it's hard to tell.  so that's 2500 * 7 or 17,500 Queries (assuming 50 products, and 50 vendors).  Are you beginning to see why it's so slow?  Now, Imagine you had 100 products and 100 vendors.  That's 10,000 loops with 7+ queries, that's at least 70,000 queries.  This is not a scalable solution.

Let's look further.. what's in all these "Getxxx" methods?  I assume there is some kind of query in each of those?  Are you possibly performing double queries each time?  Again, you're not including all the information.

To be honest, i'm quite surprised that this ONLY takes 20 seconds... i'd think it would be more like 20 minutes with any amount of data.

Comment: The SurplusViewModel is a complex object (as you can see) in our team we decided not to re-query anything in-order to avoid the processing. Your point about foreach is what I am considering, possibly to revamp that. There is no re-quering here that I am sure of. But yes data may be large

Comment: @progrAmmar - It certainly appears that you're doing lots of requerying, but again, since you did not include all the code, there's no way for us to know.  Are you saying `DbContext.GetSalesOrderDetailsFromCM()` doesn't query the database?

Comment: It does, but it does that only Once in the ViewModel :-S... 

Would it be better if we get the whole table from the database and then do all the 'WHERE' operations within the ViewModel?

Comment: @progrAmmar - Yes, it does it Once in the ViewModel, but you create 50 ViewModels (or however many products you have), each of them doing those queries each time.  You're still not getting the point.  You should be doing this all in the DATABASE, not in your code.

Comment: obviously very proactive and chatty loading of data. You likely has a very fast dev machine to load tons in 12 seconds when responding 1 request, but the deployed will be unusable. I will suggest you guys go back to the drawing board, and read some articles about performance of interactive web apps not specified to MVC, and learn some design patterns.

Comment: thanks for all the help, I guess we will have to revamp the data layer as @ErikFunkenbusch I think lack of stored procedures might just be the key.

Comment: @progrAmmar - wow, you just don't get it... stored procs have nothing to do with it.  Certainly, you CAN solve the problem with stored procs, but EF can do it all as well, but you have to write more inclusive queries rather than a bunch of single queries.  Again, it's really impossible to help you because you haven't included all the code.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I do understand what you are talking about, the app needs "LESS TRIPS TO THE DB" and a way to do it is to "AVOID GOING TO THE DB FOR THE SAME DATA" is what you are trying to say.. is it not? I am not the one who programmed the db layer but I will be this time and try to get it more optimized.

Comment: @progrAmmar - Yes, that is what you need to do.. but you can do that without writing stored procs.  You can do it with more inclusive EF queries.